# What is the song in Tokyo Ghoul with the discordant piano?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

If anyone knows, I would be so grateful. I've been looking for this one song in Tokyo Ghoul Root A that I just cannot find. It has very discordant piano music in the very beginning.

It plays in Root A episode 5, when Kaneki is Centipede and is fighting Shirohara and Amon.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Die Verwandlung](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIG6tGSdONE). Which is the 3th soundtrack on the Tokyo Ghoul EXTRA CD Vol.2 1st Mini Soundtrack